# Nautilus 3.4.2 in ubuntu 13.04

Tags: nautilus, 13.04

However many might disagree, I'm not a big fan of nautilus 3.6 in ubuntu 13.04. In my opinion it works way slower because features like search-as-you-type and multiple panes are gone. These were the two things which I used soooo much, and now they are gone (as far as I know). So is there a way to downgrade my nautilus? Or are there packages I can download to tweak nautilus or something?

regards,
Brent